# Number of $5$-letter words out of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with 2 letters occurring exactly twice.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

How do I count the number of $5$-letter words out of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with 2 letters occurring exactly twice?

My current attempt to a solution looks like this.

1. Select two *different* letters out of $\{a,b,c,d\}$: $4 \cdot 3$ possibilities.
2. Assign two occurrences of the first of these two letters to two out of the $5$ places: $\binom{5}{2}$ possibilities.
3. Assign two ocurrences of the second of these two to the remaining $3$ places: $\binom{3}{2}$
4. Choose one out of $2$ letters for the remaining space: $2$

Can I conclude that the amount of words is equal to the following?

$$
12\binom{5}{2} \binom{3}{2} 2
$$

Comment: "*Select two different letters out of...*"  This selection should have been done simultaneously, throwing your result off by a factor of two.  This is otherwise correct.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by simultaneously?

Comment: Rather than $4\cdot 3$ it should have been $\binom{4}{2}$.  Otherwise you run the risk of counting the outcome $aabbc$ by selecting $a$ **then** $b$ in the first step, assigning two $a$'s to the first two positions, the two $b$'s to the third and fourth positions and then choosing $c$ as the remaining letter and then as a completely different sequence of steps as choosing $b$ **then** $a$ in the first step, choosing to place the two $b$'s in the third and fourth positions, then choosing to place the two $a$'s in the first two positions followed by choosing a $c$ for the remaining spot.

Comment: Instead, in the first step, we simultaneously choose the two letters used for duplicates as $\{a,b\}$ (*which mind you is equal as a set to $\{b,a\}$*).  From there in the second step we decide where the "first" of these are placed where here "first" can be taken to be whichever letter picked was earliest alphabetically.  Similarly in other problems, we can assign some order in order to unambiguously determine which in a set is "first" or "second", e.g. by serial number for computers, or height for children, or name, etc...

Comment: Oh, thank you. Indeed, my solution counted the different orders in which $a$ and $b$ are selected i.e. $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2$ (as $(a,b)\neq(b,a)$ in my case) if I understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to tackle this type of question is as follows:-

The letters can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{1}=12$ ways.

We now have letters $xxyyz$ say. These can be arranged in $\frac {5!}{2!2!1!}=30$ ways.

Answer $360$.

Comment: The first line of this "*A simple way to...*" might be interpreted as to imply you think the OP's solution was not as simple, but it is essentially identical to the approach you used here.  The only simplification was using the multinomial coefficient rather than a product of binomial coefficients.

Comment: You are of course right that they are essentially the same. However, as a school exam topic I have found that students make fewer mistakes if they sort the letters first and then rearrange them. Ideally, students should be able to look at the problem in a variety of ways so that they can choose an appropriate method on really tough problems.